# Integrating cumulative distribution function of normal and exponential

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, probability-distributions

Let $F(\cdot)$ be the cdf of an exponential distribution with mean 1 and $\Phi(\cdot)$ be the cdf of the standard normal distribution. I need to show that there exists some $n$ such that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty (1- F^n(x))\Phi^n(x)~dx > 0.99.
\end{align*}
I have no idea how to proceed here. I'm fairly certain that it's probably not possible to find a closed form for the left hand-side, but I'm not sure if there's some trick I should be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define $g(x,y) = (1- F^y(x))\Phi^y(x)$ for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^+$, we have:
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = \Phi^y(x)\ln\left(\Phi(x)  \right) - \left(F(x)\Phi(x)\right)^y\ln\left(\left(F(x)\Phi(x)\right) \right) $$
Let's study the function $z\mapsto h(z) =z^y\cdot \ln(z)$ for $0<z<1$. The function $h(z)$ is decreasing (as $h'(z) = yz^{y-1}\ln(z)<0$). Then:
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = h\left( \Phi(x) \right) -  h\left( \left(F(x)\Phi(x)\right) \right)<0 \hspace{1cm} \forall y\in \mathbb{R}^+$$
because $0<F(x)\Phi(x)<\Phi(x)<1$

We deduce then $g(x,y)$ is decreasing with respect to $y$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ .

As $\int_0^{ +\infty}g(x,y)dx$ is a continuous function with respect to $y$ and
$$0= \int_0^{ +\infty}\underbrace{g(x,+\infty )}_{=0}dx <\int_0^{ +\infty}g(x,y)dx < +\infty = \int_0^{ +\infty}\underbrace{g(x,0)}_{=1}dx$$
**there exists a unique solution $y^*(\alpha)$ for the equation** $$\int_0^{ +\infty}g(x,y)dx = \alpha  \hspace{1cm} \alpha \in \mathbb{R} ^+$$

And so, for all $0<n< y^*(\alpha)$ (in particular, $\alpha = 0.99$), we have:
$$\int_0^{ +\infty}g(x,y)dx > \alpha$$

Answer (score 0):

The inequality in the OP holds for $$n\ge3.$$

I used Wolfram numerical integration to show:

for $n=1$, it [becomes](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5B%5C%2840%291-Power%5B%5C%2840%291-exp%5C%2840%29-a%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C1%5D%5C%2841%29%20%20%20Power%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C2%5D%2BDivide%5B1%2C2%5Derf%5C%2840%29Divide%5Ba%2CSqrt%5B2%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C1%5D%2C%7Ba%2C0%2C%5Cinfty%7D%5D%20): 0.761578

for $n=2$, it [becomes](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5B%5C%2840%291-Power%5B%5C%2840%291-exp%5C%2840%29-a%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%20%20%20Power%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C2%5D%2BDivide%5B1%2C2%5Derf%5C%2840%29Divide%5Ba%2CSqrt%5B2%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2C%7Ba%2C0%2C%5Cinfty%7D%5D%20): 0.980789

for $n=3$, it [becomes](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5B%5C%2840%291-Power%5B%5C%2840%291-exp%5C%2840%29-a%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C3%5D%5C%2841%29%20%20%20Power%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C2%5D%2BDivide%5B1%2C2%5Derf%5C%2840%29Divide%5Ba%2CSqrt%5B2%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C3%5D%2C%7Ba%2C0%2C%5Cinfty%7D%5D%20): 1.09101.

In the links, I used

$$\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right).$$

where $\Phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution and $\text{erf}$ is [the error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).